# How to control flow from one function to another function

Tags: c#

I am trying to call `chk_condition()` function from `find_output()` but the problem is control is not moving from find_output() function to chk_condition() function. What could be the possible error?

```
private void find_output(string a)
{
    string[] separators = new string[] { "\n" };
    foreach (string sent in a.Split(separators)
    {
        listBox8.Items.Clear();
        string sentence = sent.Replace("\r", "");
        if (sentence != "")
        {
            int s = sentence.Count();
            string[] separators1 = new string[] { " " };

            foreach (string word in sentence.Split(separators1))
            {
                listBox8.Items.Add(word);
            }
            int word_count = listBox8.Items.Count;
            chk_condition(sentence);
            if (condition_satisfy == i)
                textBox6.Text = textBox6.Text + Environment.NewLine + sentence;
        }
    }
}

private void chk_condition(string a)
{
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket `)` on the second foreach loop for starters

Comment: Do actually receive an error message or you just are not seeing the expected behavior?  If you are not seeing the expected behavior, then I am curious if you are stepping through your code with the debugger, because your method `chk_condition` does not do anything.  I also do not see where `condition_satisfy` is declared.

Comment: Not only is `condition_satisfy` not declared, but neither is `i`, and neither are ever assigned.  Are they class level variables?

Comment: control doesn't move because it doesn't compile. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code compiles - because currently there are some obvious errors** - you can debug the `find_output` method to check why `chk_condition` is never executed. One reason may be that the string `a` is empty or that your program breaks before reaching `chk_condition`.

I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio. To debug:

1. Set a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) at the beginning of `find_output`.
2. Start your application in debug mode (<kbd>F5</kbd>).
3. When the breakpoint is hit go step by step (<kbd>F10</kbd>) to see line by line how the code is executed.
4. While debugging use your mouse and hover over variables to see their current values (or use e.g. Watch Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>).
5. If your `sentence` string is not empty you will eventually reach `chk_condition`. Use step inside (<kbd>F11</kbd>) to see that the method is executed.

** Missing closing bracket in the first foreach loop. Mysterious `i` variable - is it initialized anywhere? Does it have a value?